# Simple Membership Provider case sensitive username

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

Are there any settings in Simple Membership Provider allowing to make username case sensitive? I'm building ASP.NET MVC 4 application, based on VS 2012 template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried changing the collation of the username field to a case sensitive variant on the db?

```
 ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ALTER COLUMN CharCol varchar(10) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS NOT NULL;
```

You will need to adjust the table names and types etc

Comment: Using code first approach. Any chance I could set it on a domain level?